# Unknown server tag 'cc1:AsyncFileUpload'

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ajax

I've recently downloaded Ajax Control Toolkit to use with my ASP.NET web app.
I added the AsyncFileUpload control to a web form but when I try to run the application, I get an error :

```
"Unknown server tag 'cc1:AsyncFileUpload'."
```

I have this in the ".aspx" page :

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1"    %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have the older vesion of [Ajax Control Toolkit](http://www.asp.net/(S(fu2l2uzphr2u3u45q2dnez55))/ajax/downloads/).

Comment: i downloaded the september 2009 version of Ajax Control Toolkit.

Comment: Hope you have referenced the latest downloaded version of the dll too... :-)
I dowloaded from the link I mentioned, added the reference, copied the code you posted to REGISTER, and added the AsyncFileUpload tag like this: <cc1:AsyncFileUpload ID="AsyncFileUpload1" runat="server" />....and it simply worked.....

Answer (score 3):

Dit you register the tagprefix in your .config file or in the page via e.g.

(page example):

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="cc1" Namespace="YourAjaxToolkitNamespace" Assembly = "YourAjaxToolkitAssembly" %>
```

or (web.config example):

```
<system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add assembly="Subtext.Web.Controls"
                namespace="Subtext.Web.Controls"
                tagPrefix="st" />
        <add src="~/Controls/SomeControl.ascx"
                tagName="SomeControl"
                tagPrefix="st" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
</system.web>
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, I already registered the tagprefix in the page.